# Why I can't extend to second monitor (connected via HDMI on TV) in xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xubuntu

I don't how to extend to second monitor(HDMI) and then drag a window program to right or left. I tried set it in settings manager -> display, it shows laptop screen and below HDMI monitor, but there are no options to extend to second monitor then drag to left or right a window program. How to fix it? My system is Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty.(screenshot not shows second monitor because now it is not connected)
[Display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spl4M.png)

Comment: The desktop is extended by default and mirrored if that option is selected.

Comment: @MichaelBay To clarify: When laptop is connected to TV via HDMI the TV screen display my laptop screen, any action I do on laptop is displayed on TV, when I drag a window program to right or left on laptop the TV display the same action. So far extended to second monitor(TV) not works. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks